# Multiple compiled functions modifying having access to and modifying global variables

Tags: graphs-and-networks, compile

I would like to implement the following algorithm for finding strongly connected components in Mathematica:

[image]

I would prefer to keep the structure of the pseudo-algorithm, and would like each of the procedures in the pseudo-algorithm to be its own compiled function (in order to speed up computation on large graphs), i.e. procedure *visit(v)* in the pseudo-algorithm should look something along the lines:

```
 visit = 
Compile[{{v, _Integer}}, Module[{(*local variables*)},
(* specific code needed*)
], 
CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> Automatic, 
"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> Automatic, 
"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> Automatic}, 
CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
Parallelization -> True, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

in Mathematica.

As can be seen from the pseudocode, these compiled functions would have to modify "global variables" like *rindex* array and integer *index*. How could it be possible to achieve such code structure in Mathematica?

Comment: It is possible to modify global variables but it is defanitely not a good idea since this will slow down execution so much that you'd better not compiled it.

Comment: It seems that this is the territory where a "hacked" solution will be needed. Is there then a potential workaround where rindex and index would be defined as local variables inside, say, compiled PEE_FIND_SCC3 procedure, and then all the  other compiled functions would have access to it / would be able to modify it and finally return it to the top level function (line 5 in pseudocode)?

Comment: Maybe. But `Compile` is really not made for inplace manipulations. Btw. Of course there is a very efficient implemenation available form within Mathematica. If `G` is your `Graph`, just call ``SparseArray`StronglyConnectedComponents[AdjacencyMatrix[G]]``.

Comment: Moreover, there is no efficient stack data structure available from within `Compile`. Maybe you shoud use lists of _constant_ and sufficiently large) size along with pointer indices to implement `vS` and `iS`.

Comment: I know that - ConnectedComponents[G] would do the trick too. My goal is to implement the algorithm described in pseudo-code, test it correctness / performance against Mathematica's ConnectedComponents method, and then port it to Java.

Comment: Oh, if you port it to Java, than performance cannot be your goal. ;) I f you port it anyways, why don't you implement it first in top-level Mathematica?

Comment: Just want to see if the algorithm matches (at least within the order of magnitude) the performance of Mathematica's method - and I don't think I can achieve that with a top-level Mathematica implementation. Plus, running non-compiled version on large graphs (~200 000 vertices and ~ 5 million edges) takes forever with non-compiled implementations (a general observation based on graph centrality computation algorithms that I have implemented in Mathematica - non-compiled versions of these algorithms are horrendously slower than Mathematica's (around 100 times) while compiled ones match it).

Comment: Also, I do understand that one potential solution would be to put all the code into a single giant compiled function - but that would then become a bit unwieldy and hard to understand/debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following and it seems to work. Instead of rolling out all definitions by hand (inlining), we can do it as follows.

I am going to use a simplyfied problem here. Let's consider the following compiled function that modifies a global variable.

```
submodule = Compile[{}, ++c];
```

We want to call it from another compiled function `main`.

```
main = With[{submodule = submodule},
  Compile[{},
   Block[{c = 0},
    Do[submodule[], {100}];
    c
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
   ]
  ]
```

The important point here: The previously global variable `c` becomes now local to `main`. And this is why

```
CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[main]
```

does not show any calls to `MainEvalulate`. That's good for performance.